# Problems faced during calculating FFT of wav files

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, scipy, fft

I have been trying to find FFT transform of .wav files. My initial program is (For an AMplitude - TIme Plot)

```
data_dir = 'C:/Users/asus/Desktop/Song_Test/Split/Done1.wav'

audio1, sfreq = lr.load(data_dir)
len(audio1), sfreq
Duration = len(audio1)/sfreq
print(Duration, " seconds")
time = np.arange(0, len(audio1)) / sfreq
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time, audio1)
ax.set(xlabel='Time (s)', ylabel='Sound Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

Here is the function I have till now programed.

```
import scipy
def fft_plot(audio, sampling_rate):
    n = int(len(audio))
    T = 1 / sampling_rate
    yf = scipy.fft.fft(audio)
    print(n, T)
    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), n/2.0)
    fig, ax = plt.subplot()
    ax.plot(xf, 2.0/n * np.abs(yf[:n//2]))
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("Freq")
    plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
    return plt.show()
```

The moment I call this module, using `fft_plot(audio1, sfreq)`

The following **error** pops up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/asus/PycharmProjects/untitled/Librosa_level2.py", line 92, in <module>
    fft_plot(audio1, sfreq)
  File "C:/Users/asus/PycharmProjects/untitled/Librosa_level2.py", line 59, in fft_plot
    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), n//2.0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in linspace
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 121, in linspace
    .format(type(num)))
TypeError: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

How can I sort out this float problem, kindly help me?

Comment: of primary importance to becoming a productive successful software developer you must be able to dig into and resolve issues like this on your own ... below answer is fine however its approach is a skill every software pro has mastered ...  data type issues like this one are the price you pay for using a non strict typed language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to:

```
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), n/2.0)
```

that is `n / 2.0` is supposed to be an integer:

```
num : int, optional
Number of samples to generate. Default is 50. Must be non-negative.
```

Check the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html?highlight=linspace#numpy.linspace) for details.

Your `n` is an integer, but when you divide by `2.0` you can a fraction (real number). In Python terms (and vast majority of other programming languages), you will always get a float if you divide integer by a float.

#### Solution

Make sure you pass an even number, e.g.:

```
if n % 2 == 0:
    pass # Even 
else:
    n -= 1
```